# deadlock and how we can remove it

Tags: deadlock, detection

A computer has three commonly used resources designated A, B and C. Up to three processes designated X, Y and Z run on the computer and each makes periodic use of two of the three resources. 
Process X acquires C, then B, uses both and then releases both. 
Process Y acquires A, then C, uses both and then releases both. 
Process Z acquires B, then A, uses both and then releases both. 
a) If two of these processes are running simultaneously on the machine, can a deadlock occur? If so, describe the deadlock scenario. 
b) Describe a scenario in which deadlock occurs if all three processes are running simultaneously on the machine. 
c) Modify the algorithm for acquiring resources so that deadlock cannot occur with three processes running.

Comment: cool, what seems to be the problem ?

Comment: This looks like homework, and we don't do homework, we help struggling developers solve specific problems...